# How to unserialize a list of date in extjs4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a form where I have to put the start and end dates of an event. I can choose a lot of periods. When I want to save the dates, I have to serialize them like this: 
a:2:{i:0;s:39:"2011-07-08 23:30:00,2011-07-08 23:45:00";i:1;s:39:"2011-07-22 23:30:00,2011-07-22 23:45:00";}

Can I have a function to how unserialize these dates to show them when I wanted to load the form?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can. `Ext.decode` is your friend.